# settext to highscore form other class

Tags: android, class, button, save, settext

im creating a game that has a highscore but my problem is i cant make a settext into my highscore.class coming from the button of my levelcomplete.class. my point is i want that if my highscore(button) is clicked from my levelcomplete.class it will have a textview settext automatically on my highscore.class

flow of my explanation  levelcomplete.class     = highscore(button)   =    highscore.class    =     settext 10/10

just like saving your score to highscore

levelcomplete.class

```
public class levelcomplete extends Activity  {
Button highscore;
 int highestScore;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
highscore = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
highscore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override   
       public void onClick(View v) {
        //Pass your score to other activity through Android's intent.
       Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    highscore.class);
       //THis highestScore variable will actually hold the score you get in this activity.
       intent.putExtra("score", highestScore);
       startActivity(intent);
    }
});
}
}
```

highscore.class

```
public class highscore extends Activity {
TextView score;
Button back;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.highscore);
score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    int highestScore = -1;
//Now use this score variable to set anywhere.
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras != null) {
        highestScore = extras.getInt("score");
        }



    back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_back);
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override   
       public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Back",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
 });    
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**There is 3 way to do this:**

> **First way :**( Not recommended ):

```
 public static int HighScore;
```

create this static variable on your highscore.class, You will set this public variable on your levelcomplete.class, Then you can use this variable. But this method is not a good method. Because if your device have to run lots of application , this static variable deleted by garbage collection. And our datas will be cloud data :)

> **Second way :** ( For this stiation this best for you)

Use Bundles for passing datas between activities. This is best chooice for your wants.
Send side:

```
 intent.putExtra("OUR_SCORE_TAG", INTEGER_SCORE);

 Bundle e = getIntent().getExtras();
 if (e!= null) {
  ourSCORE = extras.getInt("OUR_SCORE_TAG");
 }
```

> **Third way :**( Best way but not requered for your example this may use more complex type ):

In your levelcomplete.class,

```
public interface MyHighScoreClickListener
{
   public void onMyScoreButtonClickListener(int p_score);
}
```

and create an instance of this interface in levelcomplete.class for example;

```
public MyHighScoreClickListener listener;

highscore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override   
   public void onClick(View v) {
    //Pass your score to other activity through Android's intent.
   Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                highscore.class);
   //THis highestScore variable will actually hold the score you get in this activity.
   intent.putExtra("score", highestScore);
   startActivity(intent);
   listener.onMyScoreButtonClickListener(highestScore); // This is deadline :)
 }
 });
```

Your highscore.class have to ipmlement MyHighScoreClickListener, if you dont do this, this patternd does not run.

```
 public class highscore extends Activity implements  MyHighScoreClickListener ...
```

Then override our onMyScoreButtonClickListener method in our highscore.class and write your code that will set the text. Implement like that:

```
 public class highscore extends Activity {
 TextView score;
 Button back;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.highscore);
score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
int highestScore = -1;

@Override
public void MyHighScoreClickListener(int p_score)
{
 this.highestScore  = p_score;
 score.setText(Integer.toString(this.hightScore));

}
```

This is a design pattern. You dont have to use this pattern on this example but, this will help.

Comment: can you edit my code with your code? hahaha it gives me error

Comment: This logic coded for your code. Just need to understand the logic. This look hard but its really simple. After catch the point you will use 3. example in your complex apps.

Comment: public class highscore extends Activity implements  MyHighScoreClickListener {
 i have on error on the MyHighScoreClickListener

Comment: the error is just after the implements which is the MyHighScoreClickListener

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    highestScore = extras.getInt("score");
}
```

with this code to get your high score integer:

```
getIntent().getIntExtra("score", 0);
```

it might help you with this.